# Strange use of "for" cycle in Javascript, please explain

Tags: javascript, for-loop, cycle

I found this strange JavaScript I cannot understand. The for cycle has a strange syntax (many parameters), can you explain me how it is intended to work? Thanks

```
decode: function(s){
        for(var a, b, i = -1, l = (s = s.split("")).length, o = String.fromCharCode, c = "charCodeAt"; ++i < l;
            ((a = s[i][c](0)) & 0x80) &&
            (s[i] = (a & 0xfc) == 0xc0 && ((b = s[i + 1][c](0)) & 0xc0) == 0x80 ?
            o(((a & 0x03) << 6) + (b & 0x3f)) : o(128), s[++i] = "")
        );
        return s.join("");
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

interesting function, apparently trans-coding a certain set of chars, kind of esoteric and will only work with an ASCII code but here's the breakdown:

```
    for (var i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
        var a = s.charCodeAt(i);

        if (a & 0x80) { // (a >= 128) if extended ascii

            var b = s.charCodeAt(i + 1);

            var specialA = (a & 0xfc) === 0xc0; // a IS [À, Á, Â or Ã] essentially [192, 193, 194, 195]
            var specialB = (b & 0xc0) === 0x80; // b >= 128 & b <= 191 eg. b is not a special Latin Ascii Letter

            if (specialA && specialB) {

                var txA = (a & 0x03) << 6; // [0, 64, 128, 192]
                var txB = b & 0x3f; // 0 - 63

                s[i] = String.fromCharCode(txA + txB);

            } else {
                s[i] = String.fromCharCode(128);
                s[++i] = "";
            }
        }
    }
```

hope this helps, either way i found the decoding interesting, reminds of reading raw assembler, lol -ck

Comment: interesting decoding techniques n_n

Comment: Thank you, now it's very clear! This should be a function to decode **unicode** formatted strings (ie Ã© should be decoded to é)

Answer (score 5):

That's an ordinary `for` loop, but with a very long `var` statement in the first part.

It's just like

```
var a, b, c;
```

Also the iterator statement in the for loop contains a lot of operations instead of the loop actually having a body.

Either this function was written by a terrible programmer with no regard for readable code, or it has been intentionally minified and obfuscated.

Comment: Or there was some performance win (real or imagined) to doing it that way.

Comment: @Codemonkey: No terrible programmer could have written that.

Comment: @SLaks You're wrong. A good programmer wouldn't set all those variables in there. A good programmer cares for readability.

Answer (score 1):

The different parts of the for loop is all there, divided by the semicolons (`;`).

The var part:

```
var a, b, i = -1, l = (s = s.split("")).length, o = String.fromCharCode, c = "charCodeAt";
```

The check part:

```
++i < l;
```

The update part:

```
((a = s[i][c](0)) & 0x80) &&
        (s[i] = (a & 0xfc) == 0xc0 && ((b = s[i + 1][c](0)) & 0xc0) == 0x80 ?
        o(((a & 0x03) << 6) + (b & 0x3f)) : o(128), s[++i] = "")
```

After the `for()` statement comes a `;` right away, meaning that the loop doesn't have a body, but all the statements in the var-, check-, and update part will still be executed untill the check is no longer `true`.

Looks like someone didn't *want* their code to be readable. Where did you find it, anyway?

Answer (score 1):

**Breaking the loop into a one more readable:**

- rearranged loop parameters
- changed `(...)&&(...)` with an `if(...){(...)}`
- changed `l` to `len`
- moved `s = s.split(...)` outside the `len`

.

```
var a, b, s = s.split(""), o = String.fromCharCode, c = "charCodeAt";

for(var i = -1, len = s.length; ++i < len;){
    if((a = s[i][c](0)) & 0x80){
        (s[i] = (a & 0xfc) == 0xc0 && ((b = s[i + 1][c](0)) & 0xc0) == 0x80 ? o(((a & 0x03) << 6) + (b & 0x3f)) : o(128), s[++i] = "");
    }
}
```

---

- changed `i` initial value and how/where it increases
- moved `a = s[i][c](0)` outside

.

```
var a, b, s = s.split(""), o = String.fromCharCode, c = "charCodeAt";

for(var i = 0, len = s.length; i < len; i++){
    a = s[i][c](0);

    if(a & 0x80){
        s[i] = (a & 0xfc);
        (s[i] == 0xc0 && ((b = s[i + 1][c](0)) & 0xc0) == 0x80 ? o(((a & 0x03) << 6) + (b & 0x3f)) : o(128), s[++i] = "");
    }
}
```

---

- created `tmp` to make things easier to read
- stored the ternary operation result in `tmp`
- splitted `(s[i] == 0xc0 && tmp, s[++i] = "");` with an
  `if(...){s[++i] = "";}`
- replaced the new loop inside the your example

.

```
decode: function(s){
    var tmp, a, b, s = s.split(""), o = String.fromCharCode, c = "charCodeAt";

    for(var i = 0, len = s.length; i < len; i++){
        a = s[i][c](0);

        if(a & 0x80){
            s[i] = (a & 0xfc);

            if(((b = s[i + 1][c](0)) & 0xc0) == 0x80){
                tmp = o(((a & 0x03) << 6) + (b & 0x3f));
            }else{
                tmp = o(128);
            }

            if(s[i] == 0xc0 && tmp){
                s[++i] = "";
            }
        }
    }

    return s.join("");
}
```

**Final result** /\